# How to optimize Python simple encryption?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, encryption

So I am doing a simple cipher in **Python** and now trying to figure out how to optimize it.

I have a words `library = ['ab, 'ba', 'ac' ... ]` (library.length = 127) and each character of the input string I encode with the word from the library, so for example

```
a becomes ab, b becomes ba, etc
```

My goal is to iterate the encoding which would be something like:

```
[iterations = 3] ab -> abba -> abbabaab -> abbaabbaababba
```

Now I'm just trying to optmise it and was wondering what would be the best way?

*lock can be passed for example [31, 51, 41], where the number represents the shifting of the library to encode.

```
library = ['ab', 'ba', 'bc' ...]

def encode(message, locks=[0]):
    for key in locks:
        encrypted = ''
        for char in message:
            encrypted += library[(ord(char) + key) % 128] + " "
        message = encrypted
    return encrypted
```

Comment: The function runs in O(n) time where n is length of message.  What do you mean by optimize?  One suggestion is to remove the statement ```message = encrypted```, since it doesn't do anything except replace the original message with the encrypted version, which can also be done after the return if necessary.

Comment: My goals is to encrypt the encrypted message and this statements updates the message variable with already encrypted, to encrypt it again and so on. I'm trying to find a better way to optimize this process.

Comment: What do you mean by optimize. If I give you a different method, how will you determine it's optimality relative to yours?

Answer (score 0):

One potential inefficiency here is that you calculate and look up the appropriate library word for each character in the input string. This means if a character repeats, you do this calculation twice.

It might be more efficient to generate a 'map' of all potential input characters to words first, and then look up the appropriate word for each char in the message.

For example, assuming your message only contains lower case chars, you could do something like:

```
import string

def encode(message, locks=[0]):
for key in locks:
    encrypted = ''
    char_map = {}
    for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
        char_map[letter] = library[(ord(char) + key) % 128] + " "
    for char in message:
        encrypted += char_map[char]
    message = encrypted
return message
```

Obviously whether this is more or less efficient depends on the message length and the number of 'repeats' for each character.

However one 'repeat' which happens a lot is tht you add a space between every char. Over time, encrypting these spaces is going to add a lot of overhead, so you definitely want to map 'space' to it's word once for each loop, even if you don't do this for other characters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will look into that.

Comment: One further optimization would be to replace the second loop with `.translate`